# How not to convert an anonymous class to a regular class

Tags: java

I may be an idiot and missing something obvious. This is a thought exercise I came up with. The goal of this exercise is to do anything other than modify the abstract class Foo. Yes, I'm aware that Foo is doing something it shouldn't, and why it's wrong.

The goal: convert the anonymous class in makeFoo into a regular class (not a nested or local class).

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public final int bazz;
    public Foo(){ bazz = bar(); }
    protected abstract int bar();
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(makeFoo(5).bazz);//should print 5
        System.out.println(makeAnotherFoo(5).bazz);//should print 5 but prints 0 instead
        System.out.println(makeUglyFoo(5).bazz);//should print 5
    }

    public static Foo makeFoo(final int boop) {
        return new Foo() {
            protected int bar() {
                return boop;
            }
        };
    }

    public static Foo makeAnotherFoo(int boop) {
        return new DoesNotWork(boop);
    }

    public static Foo makeUglyFoo(final int boop) {
        return new Ugliness(boop).new Ugly();
    }
}

public class DoesNotWork extends Foo {
    private final int boop;
    public DoesNotWork(int boop){
        //implicit super();
        this.boop = boop;
        //super(); cannot be put here, that's illegal.
    }
    protected int bar() {
        return boop;
    }
}

class Ugliness {
    private final int boop;
    public DoesWork(int boop){
        //implicit super();
        this.boop = boop;
    }

    public class Ugly extends Foo {
        protected int bar() {
            return boop;
        }
    }
}
```

The standard approach to solving this problem can be found in DoesNotWork, as the name implies, it does not work. This is because boop will not be initialized until after the super constructor is called. You could use reflection to go back and change the value of bazz but that would be evil.

Which begs the question: How did they manage to make anonymous classes work? Did they give the Anonymous hidden constructor the ability to set their fields before calling the base class constructor? Or did they take an approach like I did in Ugliness?

Either way, using anonymous classes or the Ugly method, you can get around Java's design that constructors should not call methods implemented in inheriting classes that rely upon derived class data.

Comment: your design is bad. your constructor should not be allowed to call that method.

Comment: I would normally agree with you that the design is bad, but Oracle/Sun made it work for Anonymous classes anyway. If they were so wedded to the traditional notion of Good Design they would not have implemented them the way they did.

Comment: I'm talking about calling a method that can be overridden from within a constructor. That is bad design. this is strictly your abstract class.This has nothing to do with anonymous classes

Comment: I am completely aware of it's Badness. I said as much in the first paragraph of the post. Do you have anything to contribute about how Java implemented Anonymous classes?

Comment: Don't write badly designed code, and they won't give you any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes anonymous (and local) classes are magic.**

The compiler-generated contructor copies any local names referenced from the anonymous class body, and if in a non-static context (your example isn't) sets the enclosing class instance pointer(s), *before* the super ctor call. In older Java the local names referenced must be declared `final`, and for variables must be either initialized in the declaration, or not initialized and assigned exactly once on all code paths, before the occurrence of the anonymous class; since 8 or maybe 7, I don't recall exactly, they only need to be 'effectively final', which means if not declared `final` they must follow the same rules as if they were.

See this example for both the static and non-static cases. I used `Thread` as the parent class since it already has similar behavior and doesn't need another sourcefile.

```
> cat SO61315936AnonClass.java
//nopackage

public class SO61315936AnonClass {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int a = 3, b; if(g) b = 4; else b = 5;
        Thread anon1 = new Thread("anon1"){ 
            public void run(){ System.out.println("anon1:"+a+b); }
        };
        anon1.start(); try{ anon1.wait(); }catch(Exception e){}
        new SO61315936AnonClass().meth();
    }
    void meth(){
        int a = 3, b; if(g) b = 4; else b = 5;
        Thread anon2 = new Thread("anon2"){
            public void run(){ System.out.println("anon2:"+a+b); }
        };
        anon2.start(); try{ anon2.wait(); }catch(Exception e){}
    }
    static boolean g;
}
```

```
> javap -private -c SO61315936AnonClass
Compiled from "SO61315936AnonClass.java"
public class SO61315936AnonClass {
  static boolean g;

  public SO61315936AnonClass();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #10                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_3      
       1: istore_1      
       2: getstatic     #18                 // Field g:Z
       5: ifeq          13
       8: iconst_4      
       9: istore_2      
      10: goto          15
      13: iconst_5      
      14: istore_2      
      15: new           #20                 // class SO61315936AnonClass$1
      18: dup           
      19: ldc           #22                 // String anon1
      21: iload_1       
      22: iload_2       
      23: invokespecial #24                 // Method SO61315936AnonClass$1."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;II)V
      26: astore_3      
      27: aload_3       
      28: invokevirtual #27                 // Method java/lang/Thread.start:()V
      31: aload_3       
      32: invokevirtual #32                 // Method java/lang/Object.wait:()V
      35: goto          40
      38: astore        4
      40: new           #1                  // class SO61315936AnonClass
      43: dup           
      44: invokespecial #35                 // Method "<init>":()V
      47: invokevirtual #36                 // Method meth:()V
      50: return        
    Exception table:
       from    to  target type
          31    35    38   Class java/lang/Exception

  void meth();
    Code:
       0: iconst_3      
       1: istore_1      
       2: getstatic     #18                 // Field g:Z
       5: ifeq          13
       8: iconst_4      
       9: istore_2      
      10: goto          15
      13: iconst_5      
      14: istore_2      
      15: new           #49                 // class SO61315936AnonClass$2
      18: dup           
      19: aload_0       
      20: ldc           #51                 // String anon2
      22: iload_1       
      23: iload_2       
      24: invokespecial #53                 // Method SO61315936AnonClass$2."<init>":(LSO61315936AnonClass;Ljava/lang/String;II)V
      27: astore_3      
      28: aload_3       
      29: invokevirtual #27                 // Method java/lang/Thread.start:()V
      32: aload_3       
      33: invokevirtual #32                 // Method java/lang/Object.wait:()V
      36: goto          41
      39: astore        4
      41: return        
    Exception table:
       from    to  target type
          32    36    39   Class java/lang/Exception
}
```

Observe `main` calls `$1.<init>` with the string "anon1" (explicit in the source)
plus iload_1 and iload_2 which are local vars a and b, 
and `meth` calls `$2.<init>` with aload_0 (`this`) PLUS the same as $1.

```
> javap -private -c SO61315936AnonClass$1
Compiled from "SO61315936AnonClass.java"
class SO61315936AnonClass$1 extends java.lang.Thread {
  private final int val$a;

  private final int val$b;

  SO61315936AnonClass$1(java.lang.String, int, int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: iload_2       
       2: putfield      #11                 // Field val$a:I
       5: aload_0       
       6: iload_3       
       7: putfield      #13                 // Field val$b:I
      10: aload_0       
      11: aload_1       
      12: invokespecial #15                 // Method java/lang/Thread."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      15: return        

  public void run();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #26                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: new           #32                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       6: dup           
       7: ldc           #34                 // String anon1:
       9: invokespecial #36                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      12: aload_0       
      13: getfield      #11                 // Field val$a:I
      16: invokevirtual #37                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      19: aload_0       
      20: getfield      #13                 // Field val$b:I
      23: invokevirtual #37                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      26: invokevirtual #41                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      29: invokevirtual #45                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      32: return        
}
```

The ctor stores iload_2 and iload_3 (the copied a and b values) to magic fields `val$a` and `val$b` before calling the super ctor with aload_0 (`this`) and aload_1 (the `String`).

```
> javap -private -c SO61315936AnonClass$2
Compiled from "SO61315936AnonClass.java"
class SO61315936AnonClass$2 extends java.lang.Thread {
  final SO61315936AnonClass this$0;

  private final int val$a;

  private final int val$b;

  SO61315936AnonClass$2(SO61315936AnonClass, java.lang.String, int, int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: aload_1       
       2: putfield      #13                 // Field this$0:LSO61315936AnonClass;
       5: aload_0       
       6: iload_3       
       7: putfield      #15                 // Field val$a:I
      10: aload_0       
      11: iload         4
      13: putfield      #17                 // Field val$b:I
      16: aload_0       
      17: aload_2       
      18: invokespecial #19                 // Method java/lang/Thread."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      21: return        

  public void run();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #30                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: new           #36                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       6: dup           
       7: ldc           #38                 // String anon2:
       9: invokespecial #40                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      12: aload_0       
      13: getfield      #15                 // Field val$a:I
      16: invokevirtual #41                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      19: aload_0       
      20: getfield      #17                 // Field val$b:I
      23: invokevirtual #41                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      26: invokevirtual #45                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      29: invokevirtual #49                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      32: return        
}
```

Ctor puts aload_1 in magic field `this$0` as well as iload_3,4 in `val$a,b` before super ctor.

A local class can do the same -- except for the name and syntax an anonymous class *is* a local class -- but there is no way to code this in a 'regular' class. I see no better way to accomplish what you want than your two-level `Ugliness`.

Comment: Thanks! It's cool to see in SO61315936AnonClass$1(java.lang.String, int, int); how it really is setting the field values before invoking the base class constructor.